# Tyrus - pass object from client to server

Tags: object, websocket, javafx, tyrus

Is it posible to pass custom object from client to server, using Tyrus project for websocket communication. I want to build simple desktop application using JavaFX. How can I pass data that  I "collect" on client side (e.g. Object Person with name and lastname fields)  so I can save that data to database (on my server logic) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible and the form of transferred data is completely your choice.

WebSocket can transfer text or binary data, that's it. You can serialize your obect to [ObjectStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/objectstreams.html)  and send the data as binary stream, or You can use use [JAXB](https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/) to marshall and umarshall data to/from XML, or [JSON-P](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsonp.htm) for JSON (note that there are lots of other possibilities, like GSON, Jackson, ...).

If I would be in your position, I'd use JSON with whatever library I find usable - this way, when you'll extend the application scope to javascript clients, you'll be able to reuse (hopefully) everything.

Comment: I understend now. Is there some simple tutorial for this, so I can see it in code. Thank you.

Comment: @Sysrq147 hi did you find any code sample? am also having the same requirement

Comment: @jerith2 Unfortunately no. :/

Comment: @jerith2 I am pretty new to Java programming. I would like to help but not so expirienced. Sorry :(

Comment: @Sysrq147 i found the solution and posted below

Answer (score 0):

In addition to **Pavel Bucek** explanation, sample code is here

**Base64 for conversion**

```
import java.util.Base64;
```

**Serverendpoint**

```
ArrayList listobj=new ArrayList();
listobj.add("data1");
listobj.add("data2");
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
objectOutputStream.writeObject(listobj);                    
String str = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
session.getBasicRemote().sendText(str);
```

**Client (Tyrus)**

```
@OnMessage
public void onMessage(Session session, final String message) throws IOException {
    try {
        byte data[] = Base64.getDecoder().decode(message);
        bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
        ArrayList list= (ArrayList) ois.readObject();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
             System.out.println(list.get(i));
        }      
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error : " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (bis != null) {
            bis.close();
        }
        if (ois != null) {
            ois.close();
        }
    }
}
```